# How to categorize a list of numbers based on ranges?

Tags: r, distributions

I have a list containing the video game scores of around 2000 players. The scores range from 0 to 20. I want to create 3 categories of players: Good players, mediocre players, and bad players.

The simple approach would be to create 3 bins with equal ranges (13.33-20 (good), 6.66-13.33 (mediocre), 0-6.66 (bad)). However, this approach doesn't take into account the shape of the distribution. What do you think would be the best approach to form these categories? I am trying this in R, so an R specific solution would be even better.

I have attached an image of a sample of the distribution:
[Distribution of scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z56rb.png)

Comment: Look at the distribution and see if there are any "natural breaks".

Comment: This is not a programming question per se, but rather a domain specific one. Criteria for each skill group should be known in advance. What does the literature in your field say about what makes a good or a bad player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for wanting to create 3 bins should imply your exact breaks. If it does not, why bin at all, because that loses information?

As an analogy, consider human heights. There could sometimes be reasons -- as there were in early astronautics -- for identifying two threshold heights, leading to binning as too short, fine and too tall for the purposes of a space programme. (Too tall meant would not be comfortable in the cramped quarters of a space capsule, most obviously.)

But for most statistical purposes binning height, even if breaks are objective and explicit, just loses hard-won detail. That applies regardless of whether height is an outcome variable or a predictor variable.

The most important part of my paper https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0095 on how to round and bin [in Stata, but the principles are generic] are quite possibly the references explaining why binning can be a bad idea and the discussion explaining why it is often disappointing given ties, even with a criterion like quantile binning.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" approach, and whether binning is a good approach at all, will depend on what you're planning to do with these categories once you have them. Per @NickCox's thoughtful answer, binning likely isn't the best approach for most analyses. For other situations, e.g., certain types of visualizations, it may be appropriate.

From a purely practical point of view, one option is to break your data into upper, middle, and lower thirds. e.g., `dplyr::ntile()` will split the scores into `n` bins, with a (roughly) equal number of cases per bin.

```
set.seed(13)
library(dplyr)

scores <- data.frame(id = 1:15, score = rnorm(15, 10, 4))

scores %>% 
  mutate(category = recode(
    ntile(score, 3),
    "bad",
    "mediocre",
    "good"
  ))
```

```
   id     score category
1   1 12.217308     good
2   2  8.878912 mediocre
3   3 17.100653     good
4   4 10.749280 mediocre
5   5 14.570105     good
6   6 11.662105 mediocre
7   7 14.918026     good
8   8 10.946719 mediocre
9   9  8.538469      bad
10 10 14.420577     good
11 11  5.625624      bad
12 12 11.847484 mediocre
13 13  4.556062      bad
14 14  2.575891      bad
15 15  8.240578      bad
```

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which you think this is the "best" solution for the OP's problem?

Comment: Not sure I take your meaning. I don’t think I claimed this is the “best” solution, it’s merely “a” solution. Without more information about OP’s goals, I think splitting into even tertriles is one reasonable option. FWIW, I answered this before it was migrated from SO.

Comment: The question explicitly asks, "What do you think would be the **best** approach to form these categories?"

Comment: I guess I didn't interpret that phrase quite so literally. I get the sense you have an issue with my answer. Could you more explicitly let me know what the issue is and what you'd like me to do?

Comment: Please read the answer posted by Nick Cox.

Comment: @whuber I have read it, I agree, and I'm well aware of drawbacks of binning. I've also revised my answer to acknowledge this. I'm not trying to be defensive, but I'm honestly baffled by what your goal is here. Are you saying that binning data is so unacceptable that I shouldn't suggest any way of doing so? Is there some CrossValidated norm I'm running afoul of? Are you trying to get me to delete my answer? Or revise it, and if so, how? Are you just making sure I'm aware of drawbacks of binning? Again, please explicitly let me know what the issue is and what you'd like me to do.

Comment: The edit helps, but your answer still doesn't fully address the question, which I interpret as looking for a *clustering* solution.  I have no complaints about the style, format, or any other such aspect of your post, but do want to draw readers' attention to its subtler shortcomings.  For commentary on binning, please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bin*+spline+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10).